# PHP + XPath get nodes value in between Specified Dates

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

My XML file looks like :

```
<record>
    <name>John</name>
    <StartDate>01-05-2016</StartDate>
    <EndDate>30-10-2016</EndDate>
</record>
<record>
    <name>Jerry</name>
    <StartDate>29-04-2016</StartDate>
    <EndDate>30-06-2016</EndDate>
</record>
<record>
    <name>Mike</name>
    <StartDate>05-06-2016</StartDate>
    <EndDate>25-08-2016</EndDate>
</record>
```

I have Two Dates Say :

```
start date: 30-04-2016 and,
end date: 27-08-2016
```

I want to write a Xpath Query which will return all the record which have `<StartDate>` and `<EndDate>` In between the above two dates(Both Inclusive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse data and add to an array, as a stdClass or whatever you like most:

```
<?php

$xml =
    '<root>
        <record>
            <name>John</name>
            <StartDate>01-05-2016</StartDate>
            <EndDate>30-10-2016</EndDate>
        </record>
        <record>
            <name>Jerry</name>
            <StartDate>29-04-2016</StartDate>
            <EndDate>30-06-2016</EndDate>
        </record>
        <record>
            <name>Mike</name>
            <StartDate>05-06-2016</StartDate>
            <EndDate>25-08-2016</EndDate>
        </record>
    </root>';

$doc= new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//record");

$output = [];

$format = 'd-m-Y';
$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '30-04-2016');
$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '27-08-2016');

foreach($elements as $element) {
    $elementStartDate = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $element->getElementsByTagName("StartDate")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    $elementEndDate = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $element->getElementsByTagName("EndDate")->item(0)->nodeValue);

    if( ($startDate <= $elementStartDate) &&
        ($endDate >= $elementEndDate)) {
        $obj = new stdClass;
        $obj->name = $element->getElementsByTagName("name")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $obj->startDate = $element->getElementsByTagName("StartDate")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $obj->endDate = $element->getElementsByTagName("EndDate")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $output[] = $obj;
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

**Output**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#10 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Mike"
    ["startDate"]=>
    string(10) "05-06-2016"
    ["endDate"]=>
    string(10) "25-08-2016"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $startDate = date_format(date_create('30-04-2016'),'d-m-Y');
    $endDate = date_format(date_create('27-08-2016'),'d-m-Y');
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML('<records><record><name>John</name><StartDate>01-05-2016</StartDate><EndDate>30-10-2016</EndDate></record><record><name>Jerry</name><StartDate>29-04-2016</StartDate><EndDate>30-06-2016</EndDate></record><record><name>Mike</name><StartDate>05-06-2016</StartDate><EndDate>25-08-2016</EndDate></record></records>');

    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);


    //Get all XML "RECORDS"
    $elements = $xpath->query("//record");
    // Loop through the result elements of the xpath query
    if (!is_null($elements)) {
      foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        // Use two logical type variables for each element
        ($node->nodeName=='StartDate' && date_format(date_create($node->nodeValue),'d-m-Y')>=$startDate) ? $stD = 1 : $stD = 0;           
        ($node->nodeName=='EndDate' && date_format(date_create($node->nodeValue),'d-m-Y')<=$endDate) ?  $edD = 1 : $edD = 0;

        }
        // if both $stD and $edD variables do not have logical 1 as value then our $element does not meet the expected dates condition so we remove it from the xml string
        if($stD!=1 && $edD!=1) {
            $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
        }
      }
      echo $doc->saveXML();    
    }
```

Check the above output in [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/20669dfc1f9ffca4cbee4bca26862cf408c63c9f)

Comment: I do not think this will work for me. I want to check for DATE not strings values.

Comment: if you check the output xml it has only the record that meets the date condition that you want @Ajay. Additionally you check for date this way...

Comment: Yes it did happened in this case but these are not the only Dates and record i have to check for. I have thousands of record

Comment: Try it live in your script it will get your results, by the way i had to add a root tag in your xml `<records></records>` i think your xml is probably like that, holding a lot more records than this sample. The output of the above will be an xml with only the filtered results.

Comment: Check the edited answer i had a small typo error in here that was not in Sandbox example @Ajay.

Comment: @Ajay you would not have a problem even with the first example but this is the edited with `DATE` comparison, not strings :)

Answer (score 1):

> I have Two Dates Say :
>
> ```
> start date: 30-04-2016 and,
> end date: 27-08-2016
> ```
>
> I want to write a Xpath Query which will return all the record which
>   have `<StartDate>` and `<EndDate>` In between the above two dates(Both
>   Inclusive).

**Here is a single, pure XPath 2.0 expression** that selects all such `<record>` elements:

```
/*/record
[xs:date(string-join(reverse(tokenize(StartDate, '-')), '-')) ge xs:date('2016-04-30') 
and xs:date(string-join(reverse(tokenize(EndDate, '-')), '-')) le xs:date('2016-08-27')]
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "/*/record
        [xs:date(string-join(reverse(tokenize(StartDate, '-')), '-')) 
         ge xs:date('2016-04-30') 
        and xs:date(string-join(reverse(tokenize(EndDate, '-')), '-')) 
         le xs:date('2016-08-27')]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided fragment with a top element parent):

```
<t>
    <record>
      <name>John</name>
      <StartDate>01-05-2016</StartDate>
      <EndDate>30-10-2016</EndDate>
    </record>
    <record>
      <name>Jerry</name>
      <StartDate>29-04-2016</StartDate>
      <EndDate>30-06-2016</EndDate>
    </record>
    <record>
      <name>Mike</name>
      <StartDate>05-06-2016</StartDate>
      <EndDate>25-08-2016</EndDate>
   </record>
</t>
```

**the Xpath expression is evaluated** and the selected nodes (in this case just one) are copied to the output:

```
<record>
  <name>Mike</name>
  <StartDate>05-06-2016</StartDate>
  <EndDate>25-08-2016</EndDate>
</record>
```

---

**II. XPath 1.0 solution**

The equivalent XPath 1.0 expression is:

```
/*/record
    [concat(substring(StartDate,7), substring(StartDate,4,2), substring(StartDate,1,2)) 
      >= 20160430
   and not(concat(substring(EndDate,7), substring(EndDate,4,2), substring(EndDate,1,2)) 
           > 20160827)]
```

**XSLT 1.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "/*/record
        [concat(substring(StartDate,7), substring(StartDate,4,2), substring(StartDate,1,2)) 
          >= 20160430
       and not(concat(substring(EndDate,7), substring(EndDate,4,2), substring(EndDate,1,2)) 
                > 20160827)]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document as above, the same wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<record>
   <name>Mike</name>
   <StartDate>05-06-2016</StartDate>
   <EndDate>25-08-2016</EndDate>
</record>
```